# Sort key arrays with duplicate keys

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, key

So I've got three arrays. They are all equal length and are "linked" in such a way that, for example, `sums[52]`, `prods[52]`, and `indexes[52]` together make up a piece of information. They are not combined into a two or three-dimensional array for a longer, less-interesting reason.

I'm trying to sort them so that `sums` is in order, and the other two are still linked up. The code I'm using right now is as follows:

```
Array.Sort(sums.ToArray(), prods);
Array.Sort(sums.ToArray(), indexes);
Array.Sort(sums);
```

Pretty simple--it sorts the other two based on `sums`, then sorts `sums`.

Unfortunately, `sums` has many duplicate values. So sorting this way could result in something like this:

```
SUMS     PRODUCTS     INDEXES
12       67           38
12       52           107
12       60           11
13       42           98
13       17           4
18       21           60
```

`sums` is sorted perfectly in order, and `prods` and `indexes` both match. What I would like to do is sort `prods` secondarily. Since `sums` is the "key array" but has duplicates, it just throws `prods` in some random order. This is the result I'm trying to obtain:

```
SUMS     PRODUCTS     INDEXES
12       52           107
12       60           11
12       67           38
13       17           4
13       42           98
18       21           60
```

`sums` is sorted, `prods` is mapped to it and then secondarily sorted, and `indexes` is mapped to that.

I could do some vastly inefficient loop of some sort, but this setup deals with very large lists, and efficiency is important. Is there some sort of easy way of doing this? I don't see anything obvious checking out the documentation or looking up other people's uses for array key-sorting.

Comment: how much data are we talking here? maybe you should be using sqlite

Comment: or use linq and just merge the data - http://techbrij.com/linq-combine-multiple-lists-parallel-c

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this :

```
class Item
{
    public int sum;
    public int prod;
    public int index;
}


int[] sums = new int[] { 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 18 };
int[] prods = new int[] { 67, 52, 60, 42, 17, 21 };
 int[] indexes = new int[] { 38, 107, 11, 98, 4, 60 };

List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
for (int i = 0; i < sums.Length; i++)
{
    Item Item = new Item();

    Item.sum = sums[i];
    Item.prod = prods[i];
    Item.index = indexes[i];

    Items.Add(Item);
}

Items = Items.OrderBy(I => I.sum).ThenBy(I => I.prod).ThenBy(I => I.index).ToList();

sums = Items.Select(I => I.sum).ToArray();
prods = Items.Select(I => I.prod).ToArray();
indexes= Items.Select(I => I.index).ToArray();
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that the OP is asking to include `indexes` as part of the sort. Your second `ThenBy()` is unnecessary. This is also basically the same as the accepted answer in the question this question is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

Memory intensive, but maybe an efficient solution.

```
    var sums = new int[] { 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 18 };
    var prods = new int[] { 67, 52, 60, 42, 17, 21 };
    var indexes = new int[] { 38, 107, 11, 98, 4, 60 };

    var grouped = indexes.Zip(sums, (first, second) => new { Index = first, Sum = second})
        .Zip(prods, (first, second) => new { Index = first.Index, Sum = first.Sum, Prod = second}).ToList();

    foreach (var group in grouped.OrderBy(g => g.Sum).ThenBy(g => g.Prod))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", group.Sum, group.Prod, group.Index);
    }
```

results in

```
12  52  107
12  60  11
12  67  38
13  17  4
13  42  98
18  21  60
```

Comment: this is similar to Arvin's solution - I suppose you need to clarify what you mean by "efficient", do you mean in speed? memory usage?

Comment: There is no reason to use `Zip()` here. Just use `Select()` to project arbitrarily many arrays into a single anonymous type in one go. E.g. `var grouped = indexes.Select((index, i) => new { Index = index, Sum = sums[i], Prod = prods[i] });`. In any case, it's difficult for me to see how this is materially different from the other answer.

Comment: it isn't too different, after I pressed submit I saw Arvin's solution

Comment: I agree with your Zip comment, Select is better